# How can I change this code so that the command prompt closes when it finishes executing?

Tags: java, batch-file, command

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start rake.bat");
```

I want it to run rake.bat then close the command line when finished. I did it once but forgot what I did. I'm using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just don't need the `start` command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c rake.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the `Runtime` object in a variable to use it, and then call it's `exit()` method when you're done.

*exit(int status)*:

> Terminates the currently running Java virtual machine by initiating
>   its shutdown sequence.

Without storing in a variable:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To close the command line use this ...

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd exit");
```